# Access issue with exporting Stackdriver logging to BigQuery using google-cloud-python library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am aware of using google-cloud-python library to export Stackdriver logging entries to BigQuery by doing the following steps:

1) Grant `WRITER` access to `cloud-logs@google.com` for BigQuery target dataset;
2) Create a sink for BigQuery

So my question is that
Are there any other ways to let Stackdriver logging having write access to BigQuery to make a sink?

Reference: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/logging/usage.html#export-to-bigquery

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if I have to use cloud-logs@google.com for setting up
>   the access?

I believe you don't have to, based on the [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/logging/index.html) what you need is to setup the [authentication](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/core/auth.html) is either `gcloud auth application-default login` or using a service account json key file. You just need to add the cloud-logs@google.com as `writer` to the BQ dataset.

Comment: I think my question is confusing. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Other option is via the UI, creating exports to BigQuery https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I stated in my the title, I have to use google-cloud-python library cause I am automating the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are looking for different alternatives (using google-cloud-python library does work) to export stackdriver logs to BigQuery.

In [Stackdriver Logging API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/tasks/exporting-logs) you can find a guide on how to implement this with example codes in C# , GO, JAVA, NODE.JS , PHP , PYTHON and RUBY

Comment: I'm looking for other ways to let Stackdriver logging having `write` access to BigQuery to make a sink.